# Processing results from fatfree DB SQL Mapper for json encoding

Tags: json, fat-free-framework

I'm having trouble processing the returned results from a DB SQL Mapper into a recognizable json encoded array.

```
function apiCheckSupplyId() {
  /*refer to the model Xrefs*/
  $supply_id = $this->f3->get('GET.supply_id');
  $xref = new Xrefs($this->tongpodb);
  $supply = $xref->getBySupplyId( $supply_id );
  if ( count( $supply ) == 0 ) {
    $this->logger->write('no xref found for supply_id=' .$supply_id);
    $supply = array( array('id'=>0) );

    echo json_encode( $supply );
  } else {
    $json = array();
    foreach ($supply as $row){
      $item = array();
      foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $item[$key] = $value;
      }
      array_push($json, $item);
    }


    $this->logger->write('xref found for supply_id=' .$supply_id.json_encode( $json )  );
    echo json_encode( $json );
  }
}
```

This is the method I am using but it seems very clunky to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: How much Xrefs do you expect per supply? 1? or more?

Comment: One would be ideal but is not guaranteed in this wacky world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `getBySupplyId` returns an array of `Xref` mappers, you could simplify the whole thing like this:

```
function apiCheckSupplyId() {
  $supply_id = $this->f3->get('GET.supply_id');
  $xref = new Xrefs($this->tongpodb);
  $xrefs = $xref->getBySupplyId($supply_id);
  echo json_encode(array_map([$xref,'cast'],$xrefs));
  $this->logger->write(sprintf('%d xrefs found for supply_id=%d',count($xrefs),$supply_id));
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `$xrefs` variable contains an array of mappers. Each mapper being an object, you have to [cast](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper#cast) it to an array before encoding it to JSON. This can be done in one line by mapping the `$xref->cast()` method to each record: `array_map([$xref,'cast'],$xrefs)`.

If you're not confident with that syntax, you can loop through each record and cast it:

```
$cast=[];
foreach ($xrefs as $x)
  $cast[]=$x->cast();
echo json_encode($cast);
```

The result is the same.

The advantage of using `cast()` other just reading each value (as you're doing in your original script) is that it includes [virtual fields](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper#VirtualFields) as well.